# how to reverse the json array after response from webservice?

Tags: java, android, blackberry

I am getting response this

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "some message",
    "data": [
        {
            "comment_id": "43906",
            "comp_id": "116725",
            "user_id": "48322",
            "agree": "0",
            .....
            "replies": [....]
        },
        {
            "comment_id": "43905",
            "comp_id": "116725",
            "user_id": "48248",
            "agree": "0",
            .......
            "replies": [...]
        }
    ] 
}
```

I am to get all response in json array like this

```
JSONObject js =new JSONObject(response);
routeJsonArray.=js.getJSONArray("data");
```

But I need to reverse all object which is inside data array .In other word when I get response and print commant_id "43906", "43905",

But I need I reverse that objects so that when I print it first give "43905","43906",

there is solution to iterate from `i = routeJsonArray.length; i > 0; i--` But i don't want this.I want to store reverse array in another array ..

I try like this.

```
String [] routeStationString;

JSONArray localJsonArray = js.getJSONArray("data");
routeStationString = new String[localJsonArray.length()];
int k = 0;
for (int i = localJsonArray.length(); i > 0; i--) {
    routeStationString[k++] = localJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
System.out.println(routeStationString);
```

It gives error.?

Comment: Use some IDE eg eclipse for development. You are trying to store a JSONObject into a string array.

Answer (score 5):

My approach would be to create a Java Model representing a comment from your array and then proceed like this.

```
ArrayList<Comment> mList = new ArrayList<Comment>();

for(int i=0;i<routeJsonArray.length();i++){
    //get the jsonobject based on the position
    //retrieve its values
    //create a new comment object and store it to the mList
}

Collection.reverse(mList);
```

Comment: /retrieve its values value mean ,can I do like this JsonObject js= routeJsonArray.getjsonObject(i)

Comment: read the comment_id and store it to your comment object and so on for every value of every subelement in your jsonarray

Answer (score 4):

You typically want to parse this array into a POJO, a model. So the idea would be to get a `List<Comment> list` for example and then you would be able to reverse that list through `Collections.reverse(list)` method.

How do you use the data from the JSON array? you still have to iterate it, plus remember the keys and everything. the most typical solution is to parse the JSON data into java objects.

Comment: to make this even stranger i just saw your github page and circleView and the only project listed as one using it is actually an app made by a close friend of mine...

Comment: WOW! (about the Apps using it noone else contacted me for a pull request so i don't know if there are any others. God the world is too small)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray toReturn = new JSONArray();
    int length = jsonArray.length()-1;
    for(int i =length; i >= length;i--){
        try {
            toReturn.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if he wants it in another array then the edit does it

Comment: `int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--`